# Issue in Ruby on Rails app configuration using "Puma" server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, puma

I am trying to deploy my first Ruby on Rails API app in **amazon ec2**. For that I have copied my `myapp` to my home directory `/home/user`. In my server I have installed Rails using `rbenv`, also installed `mysql-client`.

In the app **Gemfile** I have added the following gems:

```
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
#for server deployment
group :production, :staging do
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano3-puma'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
end
```

**puma.rb**:

```
# Change to match your CPU core count
workers 1
# Min and Max threads per worker
threads 1, 6

app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"

# Default to production
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "production"
environment rails_env

# Set up socket location
bind "unix://#{shared_dir}/sockets/puma.sock"

# Logging
stdout_redirect "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stdout.log", "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stderr.log", true

# Set master PID and state locations
pidfile "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.state"
activate_control_app

on_worker_boot do
  require "active_record"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect! rescue ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML.load_file("#{app_dir}/config/database.yml")[rails_env])
end
```

Initially, I am not looking for **capistrano** deployment. So I am not listing `deploy.rb` file here. 
I have install nginx in the server and in the configuration file I have added the following

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf**:

```
upstream app {
   server unix:///home/user/myapp/shared/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /home/user/myapp/current/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection '';
        proxy_pass http://app;
      }

    location ~ ^/(assets|fonts|system)/|favicon.ico|robots.txt {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
      }
}
```

After adding the configuration I have restarted the server, I tired to get the server by providing the IP in the browser but  timout happened. Then I started puma server using the command

```
  bundle exec puma -e production -p 3000  -b unix:/home/user/myapp/shared/sockets/puma.sock
```

Do I have to run server like this?

Comment: Look like you missed a few steps, please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730551/rails-4-api-deployment-example-to-amazon-ec2-using-capistrano-3-nginx-puma-gi?rq=1

Comment: do I have to run server using the command **bundle exec puma -e production -p 3000  -b unix:/home/user/myapp/shared/sockets/puma.sock** in production server